# Checking if MTA-STS is enabled

Tags: security, smtp, smtp-auth

I wanted to know how we can test if MTA-STS is enabled for a domain. If I query for TXT DNS record of `_mta-sts.domainName.com` and receive a response having v=STSv1 as version, then I would assume it's enabled. However, if the response contains v=spf1, does that imply that MTA-STS is not enabled? TIA!

Comment: A TXT record can have multiple values. If the only value is `v=spf1` then MTA-STS is not enabled (not configured correctly).

Answer (score 1):

It is a bit more complicated.

In addition to the TXT record, to find out if MTA-STS is enabled for a domain, you would need to fetch the policy file at `https://mta-sts.{yourdomain.tld}/.well-known/mta-sts.txt` as in that file the state *none, testing* or *enforce* should be listed. If '*enforce*' is there, only then you may conclude MTA-STS is enabled. (So both TXT-record and *enforce* setting.)

Easy assist? Check this: https://www.mailhardener.com/tools/mta-sts-validator and fill out a domain. The site will explain every value.

The TXT record you refer to only suggests that a policy file should exists, not that the policy itself is "set to on". Secondly, the TXT record displays a versionnumber of the policy.

Comment: In addition, the TXT record `_mta-sts.example.com` must exist. If it does not exist, a request for `https://mta-sts.example.com.well-known/mta-sts.txt` is not performed.